# Weird behaviour of Hypelink with \href to open an external PDF file

Tags: beamer, hyperref, vspace

Consider the following two beamer codes:

**Code 1:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=.8]
    \frametitle{\href{run:Doc.pdf}{Click1}}
    \href[page=5]{file:Doc.pdf}{Click2}
    \vspace{1cm}
    ~\\
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Code 2:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=.8]
    \frametitle{\href{run:Doc.pdf}{Click1}}
    \href[page=5]{file:Doc.pdf}{Click2}
    \vspace{10cm}
    ~\\
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The only difference between Code 1 and Code 2 is that in Code 2 we have `\vspace{10cm}` whereas in Code 1 we have `\vspace{1cm}`. In Code 1, both Click1 and Click2 work properly. In Code 2, however, Click2 does not work. Why is that and how to fix Code 2?

Note that Code 2 is a simplified part of a tex file that I have and I used it here to reproduce the error. In my tex file, instead of `\vspace{10cm}` there is a large body of text including a photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit smaller value and border around the links you can see the problem (I removed the navigation bars only to have less links in the pdf):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\pdfcompresslevel0
\hypersetup{pdfborder={1 1 1}}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=.8]
    \frametitle{\href{run:Doc.pdf}{Click1}}
    \href[page=5]{file:Doc.pdf}{Click2}
    \vspace{8.5cm}
    ~\\
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With this settings you get a warning in the log that the frame is shrunk more than expected:

```
Class beamer Warning: Frame text is shrunk by a factor of 3.42255 percent inste
ad of .8 percent on input line 75.
```

And the effect is that the link rectangle is no longer at the same position as the link text:

[image]

With larger values the link rectangle moves out of the page. I don't think that there is an easy fix. Avoid shrinking a page if there are links in it.